# Certain $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: polynomials, fields, involutions

Let $\beta$ be the following involution on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
$\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Assume that $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}$ and  $k \in K_{\beta}$ satisfy:

**(i)** $s_1,s_2$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

**(ii)** $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_1,k)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

> When $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$?

Please notice that this is not the original question; the original question said: Is it true that $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$?.

**Remark:** In the spirit of the comment, take $s_1=x, s_2=y^4, k=xy$.
Then, perhaps a plausible additional condition that will guarantee that 
$\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$ is:
$y \notin \mathbb{C}(s_i,k)$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.

I have also asked the above question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419204/certain-u-v-w-in-kx-y-such-that-ku-v-w-kx-y?noredirect=1#comment7031915_3419204).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The one who voted to close my question: If you think that my question is too easy for MO, please could you answer it (here or at MSE) and then I will delete it.

Comment: Try $\mathbb{C}(xy^4, xy^8, y)$.

Comment: @KevinCasto, very nice counterexample! Thank you.

Comment: Addressing your edit: try $\mathbb{C}(y^4, xy^4, xy)$. This problem is harder than only taking monomial generators, but it might be worth considering just the monomial case and converting the problem into one of linear algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @KevinCasto, thank you very much for your comment! Please 3 questions:  (1) Do you think that my problem is 'solvable'?  In particular, is it true that $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$, under the additional condition that $y \notin \mathbb{C}(s_i,k)$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$? (2) Did you mean that  my question can be solved in two steps: (a) Special case where $\{s_1,s_2,k\}$ are monomials. (2) General case. (3) What if we replace $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ by $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$? Thanks.